# Change slot props from child

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

In Vue JS, how to pass a component as a prop (or a slot) of another component, while been able to set it's own props from a grandchild component ?

**Parent :**

```
<template>
  <Child>
    <SomeComponent />
  </Child>
</template>
```

**Child :**

```
<template>
  <GrandChild>
    <slot></slot>
  </GrandChild>
</template>
```

**Grandchild :**

```
<template>
  <slot :content="content"></slot> //Setting the props of <SomeComponent/> here
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "v-slot:default"!

Parent :

```
<template>
  <Child>
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
      <SomeComponent :content="slotProps.content"/>
    </template>
  </Child>
</template>
```

Child :

```
<template>
  <GrandChild>
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
        <slot :content="slotProps.content"></slot>
    </template>
  </GrandChild>
</template>
```

Grandchild :

```
<template>
  <slot :content="content"></slot>
</template>
```

I recommend you refer to this document.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#scoped-slots